# Editing an Object in Database from Django Form

Tags: django, database

How can you edit an existing object in a database from a form? I use this for example:

`obj_ex = Model(column = value, column2 = value2)
 obj_ex.save()`

However this doesn't update my object in the database. I have tried to access the pk of the entry and save the values of the entry with the pk of `x` but I still can't update the table.

Is there a way to use an `.update()` type to update objects? Or is there another way to update a table?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code for your form.

Comment: See also [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I had multiple entries in the table, I used an update field to updated the cells in the table. This is what I did:

```
o = Model.objects.filter(x=value0).values_list("id", flat=True) #where x is posted information getting the primary key (id).
Model.objects.select_related().filter(id = o).update(column = value, column2 = value2)
```

The update field does not need a `.save()` as it will update the table when it is called.

I would like to thank Udi for his answer as it did step me into the right direction.

Comment: Keep in mind calling `.update()` will skip your `.save()` method which sometimes includes some functionality

Comment: Try also: `Model.objects.filter(x=value0).update(column=value, column2=value2)`

Comment: That looks a lot cleaner, thanks. What do you mean by the first comment? Is using `.update()` worse than using a `.save()` by any means? I', still new to Django and learning my way around.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
obj_ex = Model(column=value, column2=value2)
```

Which creates a new instance (and later a new db record) try:

```
o = Model.objects.get(pk=1234)  # load instance with id=1234 to memory from db
o.column = value
o.column2 = value2
o.save()
```